# In Perforce on Unix, how do you add a directory that is a symbolic link?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I have created a symbolic link directory in Unix and I would like to add it to perforce.

(this question relates to symlinks on Unix. [Windows symbolic links can have very different behaviour from Unix.)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)

- ../blah/dir1 is the source directory, which contains files that are already in Perforce
- dir2 is the symlink to the source directory that I want to check in

```
ln -s ../blah/dir1 dir2
```

If I right-click on "dir2" in the p4v GUI, it will add every file under ../blah/dir1 as a new file (even if these files are already in Perforce) and fubar everything.

If I do a "p4 add dir2" from the command line, it will add every file under ../blah/dir1 as a new file (even if these files are already in Perforce) and fubar everything.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: engtech, make that an answer not a comment.  :)

Comment: thanks, I didn't see that option.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add the symbolic link from the shell using the -t option to set the symlink type.

```
p4 add -t symlink dir2
```

Comment: I find I need to use -f : p4 add -f -t symlink dir2

Answer (score 4):

Perforce is able to detect symlinks itself and no special options need to be added in the command. Just regular command like following suffices the need

```
p4 add <sym link filename>
```

Comment: Actually, no. I got `Null directory (//) not allowed in ...` w/o `-t symlink`, while it worked fine with it.