# Create a symbolic link for a file in perforce

Tags: perforce, p4v

I have a file in one branch //depot/Dest/file1.txt and other branch is  //depot/Src/

I want to have a symbolic link from //depot/Src/file1.txt pointing to //depot/Dest/file1.txt by using p4v .

Can I do that using  p4v ?

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923239/in-perforce-on-unix-how-do-you-add-a-directory-that-is-a-symbolic-link

Comment: It is adding symbolic linked folder in perforce . My question is can we have a symbolic link to a file  in perforce between 2 different branches

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when you sync '//depot/Src/file1.txt' in your client? Are you expecting that you will also sync '//depot/Dest/file1.txt' at the same time? Will you always have both of those files in your workspace? Or will you typically only have one of them?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Use streams.  Stream definitions let you have a single depot file shared among multiple streams via the "import" path type.

```
Stream: //depot/Src
Paths:
    share ...

Stream: //depot/Dest
Parent: //depot/Src
Paths:
    share ...
    import file1.txt
```

Option 2: Create an OS symlink and add it to the depot.  I believe you can do this with a file as well as with a directory.